# No contract compiled coupled with a lot of parserror

Tags: solidity

```
function retrieveEHRs(string stringToBytes32, string retrieve_name, address userPK,string storageName, address AreaID, address PatientID, string Hash_value)
    onlyAdminp public{
        bytes32 key=stringToBytes32(retrieve_name);
        Look up the EHRs data in DHT table;
        DTHtable[key].storageName=storageName;
        DTHtable[key].AreaID=AreaID;
        DTHtable[key].PatientID=PatientID;
        DTHtable[key].Hash_value=Hash_value;
        emit DataResult(userPK);
        //DTHtable[key];
    }
```

> look up the ehrs says parseerror: expected ; but go identifier

Comment: My whole code when compiled says no contract compiled. i would love to show the whole code but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a comment that is not marked as a comment, and the compiler sees it as a syntax error.

```
Look up the EHRs data in DHT table;
```

Fix it by either prepending `//` or wrapping it in `/*` and `*/`

Examples:

```
// Look up the EHRs data in DHT table;
/* Look up the EHRs data in DHT table; */
```